# ui-router cant find constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following setup:

```
   var lbApp = angular.module('lbApp',
    [
        'Main',
        'user',
        'Dashboard',
        'ui.router'
    ]
);

lbApp.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    all: '*',
    admin: 'admin',
    editor: 'editor',
    guest: 'guest'
});

lbApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.tmp.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    $stateProvider.state('adminDashboard', {
        url: '/adminDashboard',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboards/admin/dashboard.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'Dashboard',
        data: {
            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.admin, USER_ROLES.editor]
        }
    })
    ;
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

However when i run my site i get an error message saying:

```
ReferenceError: USER_ROLES is not defined
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should inject

> USER_ROLES

inside your config like so:

```
lbApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,USER_ROLES) {
```

Comment: I beat you by 45 seconds :-)

Comment: hence your rep, it all adds up :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to inject dependency

```
lbApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,USER_ROLES)
```